# Bloch Sphere appears for some reasons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to draw something called the bloch sphere, but I got its image even when it's not supposed to happen.  I wrote the following codes.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations

class quantum_gates:
    def __init__(self,x2,y2,z2):

    x2 = input("x:")
    y2 = input("y:")
    z2 = input("z:")
    x2 = float(x2)
    y2 = float(y2)
    z2 = float(z2)
    self.x2 = x2
    self.y2 = y2
    self.z2 = z2

    if self.x2**2 + self.y2**2 + self.z2**2 != 1:
        print("Wrong input(x^2+y^2+z^2 has to be 1)")
    else:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        ax.set_aspect("equal")
        u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
        x = np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
        y = np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
        z = np.cos(v)
        ax.set_xlabel('x')
        ax.set_ylabel('y')
        ax.set_zlabel('z')
        ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color="black")
        ax.quiver(0,0,0,x2,y2,z2,color="red")
```

For example, when I put `quantum_gates(2,3,1)`,which is `self.x2^2 + self.y2^2 + self.z2^2 != 1`, I get the image of the sphere and a red arrow.

What am I supposed to do to get them only when `self.x2^2+self^y2+self.z2^2 = 1`?

Comment: please fix your identation. why are you providing `x2,y2,z2` to `__init__()` if you overwrite them againby inputs() inside __init__()?

Comment: I should have written the code like x2 = float(input("x:")), thank you so much for mentioning.

Comment: No - the question is _ why are you _providing `def __init__(self,x2,y2,z2)`  AND also ask for input inside it? `x2 = input("x:") y2 = input("y:") z2 = input("z:")` wic overrides the given `x2,y,2,z2` overrides whatever you provided - that makes no sense

Comment: That's because I'm building a simulator of something called a quantum bit, and  I want to do some calculation that I wrote later(not in the code above) to a user input.